# Convert Ordinal Number format to Number

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need to convert FIRST/ SECOND /THIRD /FOURTH /FIFITH .... to 1 2 3 4 5 ....
Is there a function in oracle.
Other way is possible as below,but I want reverse

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(3,'J'), 'fmJSPTH') FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice question!

```
create table t (w varchar2(30));

insert into t values ('First');
insert into t values ('THIRD');
insert into t values ('eleventh');
insert into t values ('Twenty-eighth');
insert into t values ('two hundred fifty sixth');

select 
  t.w, dict.n
from t
left join (
  select
    level n,
    regexp_replace(to_char(to_date(level,'J'),'fmJSPTH'),'[^A-Z]') w
  FROM dual
  connect by level <= 1000
) dict on regexp_replace(upper(t.w),'[^A-Z]')=dict.w
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1669f/5)

Comment: WOWWW AWESOME!! YOUR SIMPLY GREAT! APPLAUSE TO YOU!!